# how to only display decimals in ggplot axis tick labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I get ggplot to display only decimals in the axis tick labels?

Consider a toy dataframe like the following, for which all the variables are < 1 in absolute value:

```
set.seed(42)

x <- rnorm(n=500, sd = 0.1)
y <- 0.05 + 2*x + rnorm(n=500, sd = 0.05)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

summary(df)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Is it possible to have `.xx` instead of `0.xx` on the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `labels` argument of the `scale_x_continuous()`, in this case a lambda style function:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=~sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.1f", .x)))
```

Comment: really neat, thanks! For potential future viewers of this question: to display ```n``` decimals, one simply has to change ```%.1f``` to ```%.nf```